# Encoding metadata in pdf file with pdfx package

Tags: pdftex, pdfx

### Problem (*En* - google translate)

Hello,

I compiled a pdf / a-1b (pdf / x-1) file using the **[pdfx](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfx)** package. Metadata (xmpdata) used Cyrillic characters. Unfortunately **pdfx** incorrectly sets the metadata encoding:

- Cyrillic characters in the metadata are displayed as an array of bytes (viewer SumatraPDF, Foxit Panthom);
- Cyrillic characters in the "Author" attribute are displayed **correctly**!
- Adobe Acrobat Pro correctly displays all metadata if the user has not set a value for `\URLlink`. If the value of `\URLlink` is defined,
  then Adobe Acrobat Pro starts displaying all the attributes as a byte array.

### Проблема (*Rus* - original)

**Заголовок темы:** Кодировка метаданных (eXtensible Metadata Platform, XMP) pdf файла с пакетом **pdfx**.

Привет,

я собрал pdf/a-1b (pdf/x-1) файл с использованием пакета **[pdfx](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfx)**. В метаданных (xmpdata) использовались кириллические символы. К сожалению **pdfx** некорректно устанавливает кодировку метаданных:

- кириллические символы в метаданных отображаются в виде массива байтов (просмотрщик [SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html), Foxit Panthom);
- кириллические символы в атрибуте "Автор" отображаются **корректно**!
- Adobe Acrobat Pro корректно отображает все метаданные, если пользователь не установил значение для `\URLlink`. Если значение `\URLlink` определено, то Adobe Acrobat Pro начинает отображать все атрибуты в виде массива байтов.

### Attempt to solve (*Rus:* Попытка решения)

Adding `\pdfinfo` to`\jobname.xmpdata` does not help:

(*Rus:* Добавление `\pdfinfo` в `\jobname.xmpdata` не помогает:)

```
  \pdfinfo{
  /Author (The Author)
  /Title (Заголовок)
  /Subject (Тема)
  /Keywords (Ключевое слово1, два, три)
  /Publisher (Издатель)
  /Copyright (Правообладатель)
  /Copyrighted (True)
  /PublicationType (Book) 
}
```

The **[hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)** package works fine, but only until you use the **pdfx** package :(

(*Rus:* Пакет **[hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)** работает прекрасно, но только до тех пор пока не используешь пакет **pdfx** :( )

```
%\usepackage[]{hyperref}            % Гиперсылки в тексте (Лучше добавлять самым последним)

%--- Настройки PDF
\hypersetup{
pdftitle={Название документа}
,pdfauthor={Автор}
,pdfsubject={Тема}
,pdfkeywords={Ключевые слова}
}
```

### Screenshot of the problem (*Rus:* Скриншот с проблемой)

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Screenshot Adobe Acrobat without defining `\URLlink` (*Rus:* Скриншот без определения `\URLlink`)

[image: Screenshot Adobe Acrobat without defining <code>\URLlink</code>]

Screenshot Adobe Acrobat with defining `\URLlink`. Some metadata disappeared altogether (*Rus:* Скриншот с определением `\URLlink`. Некоторые метаданные вообще исчезли)

[image: Screenshot Adobe Acrobat with defining <code>\URLlink</code>]

### MWE (*Rus:* Минимально работающий пример)

```
% File \jobname
\documentclass{scrbook}

\input glyphtounicode.tex           % Копирование символов в pdf (должен стоять до fontenc)
\pdfgentounicode=1                  % ----//----

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % Внутренняя кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Кодировка исходников книги

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % Локализация и переносы
\usepackage[a-1b, cyrxmp]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
\Russian
\frontmatter                                                        
\chapter{Глава 1}    
бла бла бла
\end{document}
```

Metadata is moved to a separate file (*Rus:* Метаданные вынесены в отдельный файл).

```
% File \jobname.xmpdata
\Title{Во имя жизни - Title}
\Author{М. Шубич}
\Publisher{Издательство Pub}
\Subject{Тематика The Subject}
\Language{ru-RU}
\Copyright{Авторское право Copyright}
\Contributor{Участники проекта Contributor}
\CopyrightURL{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}
\PublicationType{book}
\Source{https://github.com/gmaFFFFF/shubich-vo-imja-zhizni}
\Keywords{Ключевое слов\sep book\sep Keywords}
\ISBN{978-5-11111-111}
\CreatorTool{LaTeX with pdfx}
%\URLlink{https://github.com/gmaFFFFF/shubich-vo-imja-zhizni/main.pdf}
```

### Question (*Rus:* Вопрос)

How to make all metadata available for reading in the pdf viewer, but retain the ability to create pdf/x, pdf/a documents?

What to do with `\ URLlink`?

(*Rus:* Как сделать все метаданные доступными для чтения в просмоторщике pdf, но сохранить возможность создания pdf/x, pdf/a документов?

Что делать с `\URLlink`?)

Comment: I'm not sure if pdfx is really doing something wrong. pdfx does encode the title differently than hyperref is doing it, but as adobe shows the title correctly it could be valid code and sumatra being faulty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If only SumatraPDF could not display the characters, but Foxit Panthom also does not cope. And if you add `\URLlink`, then Adobe Acrobat does not cope. *Rus:* Если бы только SumatraPDF не мог отобразить символы, но ведь ещё и Foxit Panthom не справляется. А если добавить `\URLlink`, то и Adobe Acrobat не справляется.

Comment: different pdf viewer often use similar internal libraries. But I don't have the time to check the encoding created by pdfx now so I really can't say if pdfx is wrong or not.  I couldn't reproduce your problem with \urllink, if I enable it it worked fine in adobe pro.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer After your message I tried again to collect pdf with the definition of `\ URLlink`. It turned out that in my case not only Cyrillic metadata (except the author) began to be displayed as an array of bytes, but some other metadata, including "keywords", disappeared. I do not understand why it does not work for me. Adobe Pro XI. I added the main post with the corresponding screenshots. Thanks for participating I will look further.

Comment: *Rus:* После Вашего сообщения еще раз попробовал собрать pdf с определением `\URLlink`. Оказалось, что в моем случае не только кириллические метаданные (кроме автора) стали отображаться массивом байтов, но и исчезли некоторые другие метаданные, в том числе, "ключевые слова". Не пойму почему у меня не работает. Adobe Pro XI. Дополнил основной пост соответствующими скриншотами. Спасибо за участие буду искать дальше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to one of the authors of the package **pdfx** Ross Moore, the problem is solved in version 1.6.3.

(Rus - original)
Благодаря одному из авторов пакета **pdfx** Ross Moore проблема решена в версии 1.6.3.